Reading ECG wave data from .dat and .hea file from SD card with Arduino DUE to produce it on DAC pin
I am trying to produce an ECG wave on the DAC pin of the Arduino DUE.
Here are my setup details.
SD card is attached to Arduino DUE with SPI connections.
I have 2 files (.dat and .hea) of ECG data on the SD card.
I want to read that Signal data and produce that signal on the DAC0/1 pin of the Arduino DUE.
Following are the contents of the header file and I want to produce only the lead II signal
01000_lr 12 100 1000

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 -710 1613 0 I

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 -661 1979 0 II

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 49 332 0 III

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 686 63702 0 AVR

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 -379 619 0 AVL

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 -306 1111 0 AVF

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 260 63466 0 V1

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 -229 65137 0 V2

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 -195 2607 0 V3

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 160 64808 0 V4

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 -70 990 0 V5

01000_lr.dat 16 1000.0(0)/mV 16 0 -205 1775 0 V6


    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <SD.h>
    
    const int chipSelect = 4; // Change to your SD card CS pin
    const int dacPin0 = DAC0; // DAC output pin
    const int signalSamplingRate = 1000; // Sampling rate in Hz
    const int signalDelay = 10000000 / signalSamplingRate; // Microseconds delay
    const int numberOfSignals = 12; // Total number of signals as per .hea file
    const int signalIndexLeadII = 1; // Assume Lead II is the 2nd signal (index 1 in 0-based indexing)
    
    // Function to read a 16-bit signed integer from the binary file
    int16_t read16bitSigned(File &file) {
      int16_t value;
      file.read((char *)&value, 2);
      return value;
    }
    
    void setup() {
      // Initialize Serial (optional, can be removed if not needed)
      Serial.begin(115200);
      while (!Serial) {
        ; // Wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
      }
    
      // Initialize SD card
      Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
      if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
        Serial.println("Initialization failed!");
        return;
      }
      Serial.println("Initialization done.");
    }
void loop() {
 // Open the .dat file
 File dataFile = SD.open("01000_lr.dat");
 if (!dataFile) {
   Serial.println("Error opening 01000_lr.dat");
   return;
   }

// Read and output data continuously
 while (dataFile.available()) {
 // Skip to the desired signal
 for (int i = 0; i <<numberOfSignals; i++){
int16_t data = read16bitSigned(dataFile);
    
 // Process Lead II signal
 if (i == signalIndexLeadII) {
    int scaledDataLeadII = map(data, -32768, 32767, 0, 4095);
    analogWrite(dacPin0, scaledDataLeadII);
    
   // Delay to match the sampling rate
   delayMicroseconds(signalDelay);
   }
  }
      }
    
  // Close the file and reopen it to loop continuously
  dataFile.close();
  }


Question#1: This code reads the files but does not produce the signal accurately, how can I read it accurately because my data is 16bit and DAC is 12 bit resolution.
Question#2: What is the method to shift the data from the SD card into the internal memory once and then read that data to produce the signal continuously?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You seem to know what you want to do, so what is the question?

I have added the questions, thanks for notifying.

Please reformat the code with proper indentation. It's hard to follow but looks like you're trying to open and close the file every time around the loop, which is a bad idea.

what does this mean? ... does not produce the signal accurately ... what were you expecting? ... what actually happens? ... please edit your question ... the answers to these questions do not belong in comments
